# Trouble translating this regex to bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have the following working regex that I tested in regex101

```
^function\s(\w+)\(\)\s{$
```

for the following test string

```
function hello() {
  echo "Hello World"
}


function get_aws_credentials() {
  echo "Getting AWS Credentials
}
```

My goal is to get all function names defined in that file and that's what my original regex does, but not in bash.

The problem is that it doesn't work in bash or zsh (I really only care about bash though).

I have researched it and saw some alternatives, like replacing the `\w+` for `[[:alnum:]]`, but that didn't work either.

This is how I'm testing it: `cat utils.sh | grep "^function\s(\w+)\(\)\s{$"`

Any idea of what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: It does seem to for me when I specify the `-E`/`--extended-regexp` switch: `grep -E '^function\s(\w+)\(\)\s{$' utils.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work or are you trying to create a universal regex for every file type?

```sh
# Get all function names defined in a bash script file
# Usage: script.sh <script_file>

function get_functions() {
    local FUNC_NAME=$(basename $1)
    local FUNC_NAMES=$(grep -o '^function [a-zA-Z0-9_]*' $1 | sed 's/function //')
    echo "$FUNC_NAMES"
}
```

Comment: Most solutions here worked for `bash`, but this one get's a bonus point for also working in `zsh`!

This is my final implementation
`cat utils.sh | grep -o "^function [a-zA-Z0-9_]*" | sed "s/function //"`

Answer (score 1):

Have to be careful with regex sites: you need to know what *flavor* of regex you're using.

Your grep might have a `-P` option to enable PCRE, so try this:

```sh
grep -oP '^\s*(function\s+)?\K\w+(?=\s*\(\))'
```

Given your input, this outputs

```
hello
get_aws_credentials
```

A couple of notes about the pattern:

- the `function` keyword is optional
- there can be whitespace between the function name and the parentheses
- the opening brace does not have to appear on same line

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -Po '^function \K[^(]*' utils.sh
hello
get_aws_credentials
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n s'/^function \([^(]*\).*/\1/p' utils.sh
hello
get_aws_credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that '\w' is not a valid character class in bash regular expressions.

You can use the '[[:alnum:]]' character class instead:

```
cat utils.sh | grep "^function\s\([[:alnum:]]+\)\(\)\s{"
```

Alternatively, you could use the '[[:alpha:]]' character class, which would match any letter:

```
cat utils.sh | grep "^function\s\([[:alpha:]]+\)\(\)\s{"
```

Comment: This was my first attempt to fix it, that doesn't work